# Scanner Cannot be Dereferenced

Tags: java

My issue is to create a method called getScanner, and each time it is called, another method can call getScanner to get the next line of input.

Code:

```
public static void getScanner() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
}

public static String getInput() { 
    String userInput = getScanner().nextLine();
    return userInput
}
```

Error

```
   error: void cannot be dereferenced
                          String userInput = getScanner().nextLine();
                          1 error
```

Essentially, I have multiple methods that need to user Scanner as input, rather than declaring a global or local variable, I want to call one method that will create a Scanner as input each time it is called and assign a variable to this input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set void return type which returns nothing. Since you require a scanner object, return a Scanner in the method.

```
public static Scanner getScanner() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    return input }

public static String getInput() { 
    String userInput = getScanner().nextLine();
    return userInput }
```

Comment: You are not returning anything

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning an instance of `Scanner`. Use:

```
public static Scanner getScanner(){
return new Scanner(System.in);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Working Code. Tested and Compiled.

```
public class testj
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(getInput());
    }

    private static String getInput()
    {
        String userInput = getScanner().nextLine();
        return userInput;
    }

    private static Scanner getScanner()
    {
        return new Scanner(System.in);
    }
}
```

We have to specify in the method header, what `object` is getting returned.

---

Shorter version for **getInput()**

---

You can also modify this method as below

```
    private static String getInput()
    {
        return getScanner().nextLine();
    }
```

Comment: On a lighter note, you say _"Working Code. Tested and Compiled"_ but you didn't add a class :p